# Check whether my query is using index on attribute using ANALYZE

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have installed a b-tree index on `o_orderdate` attribute.

I have this query:

```
explain select
    o_orderpriority,
    count(*) as order_count
from
    orders
where
    o_orderdate>='01/07/1993'
and
    o_orderdate<'01/10/1993'
and
    exists (select * from commitdate_before_receiptdate_view) -- mat view
GROUP by
    o_orderpriority
ORDER by
    o_orderpriority
```

this is giving me:

```
"Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=734229.48..734230.75 rows=5 width=24)"
"  Group Key: orders.o_orderpriority"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"    ->  Seq Scan on commitdate_before_receiptdate_view  (cost=0.00..1714549.24 rows=33184824 width=0)"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=734229.43..734230.60 rows=10 width=24)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Params Evaluated: $0"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=733229.41..733229.42 rows=5 width=24)"
"              Sort Key: orders.o_orderpriority"
"              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=733229.30..733229.35 rows=5 width=24)"
"                    Group Key: orders.o_orderpriority"
"                    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..732048.00 rows=236260 width=16)"
"                          One-Time Filter: $0"
"                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..732048.00 rows=236260 width=16)"
"                                Filter: ((o_orderdate >= '1993-07-01'::date) AND (o_orderdate < '1993-10-01'::date))"
```

How can I check whether my query is using the index I installed on `o_orderdate` attribute?

According to [this article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/how-parallel-query-works.html), the optimizer has determined that parallel query is the fastest solution, creating a `Gather` node. So it isn't using the B index on `o_orderdate?`

Comment: As your title suggests, it would be best to use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` not just `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @jjanes why? thank you. The latter actually executes the query while the former just estimates it?

Comment: Yes.  Also, we could see the count of rows in the table (via "removed by filter"), which currently we can't see in even estimated form.

Comment: @jjanes I noticed that "records removed by filter" according to EXPLAIN ANALYZE is 4.808.776 but if I run the query with `select count(*) from orders where not((o_orderdate >= '1993-07-01'::date) AND (o_orderdate < '1993-10-01'::date))` I get 14.426.329. Why is that?

Comment: It is hard to interpret isolated lines of a plan.  Do they have the same number of parallel workers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not using the index, but 'parallel' does not show us that, because index scans can also be done in parallel.  It is the presence of 'seq scan' and absence of '[parallel] [bitmap] index [only] scan' which tells us that.  A plain EXPLAIN is enough to tell us that it doesn't use the index, but can't tell us much about *why* it chose not to, which I assume is what you are trying to get at.